# Tweaking bundle config only for particular bundle in application

Tags: rest, symfony, configuration, bundle

I have Symfony application which uses FOSRestBundle, and have some 
settings configured in main config.yml:

```
fos_rest: 
    service: 
        serializer: my.serializer 
        view_handler: my.viewHandler 
    view: 
        view_response_listener: false 
        failed_validation: 200
```

Now I am building new public API bundle, and I have following problem. 
When I test my API from browser, I get

```
Unable to find template "". 
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

It works from 
curl. I guess it fails because browser asks for html content type, and 
I don't need any template, I just want to return xml/json like this:

```
return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle(View::create(array('x' => 'y')));
```

I use to fix this with updated config:

```
fos_rest: 
    service: 
        serializer: my.serializer 
        view_handler: my.viewHandler 
    view: 
        view_response_listener: false 
        failed_validation: 200 
    format_listener: 
       default_priorities: [xml, json] 
       fallback_format: xml
```

but then I broke some actions in exising application (other bundles 
which use FOSRestBundle). 
Is there a way to tweak FOSRestBundle (or any other bundle) config 
only for my public APi bundle? 
I tried with Extension:

```
$loader = new YmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../ 
Resources/config')); 
        $loader->load('services.yml');
```

where services.yml is:

```
fos_rest: 
  service: 
    view_handler: my.public.api.view_handler 
  format_listener: 
    default_priorities: [xml, json] 
    fallback_format: xml
```

but I got:

```
InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the 
configuration for "fos_rest".
```

Answer (score 4):

When you are installing the packages by composer you need to add the bundles to app/AppKernel.php manually:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
        new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
        new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
        // ...
    );
}
```

[Here is more info.](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md#c-enable-the-bundle)

Answer (score 4):

when we work with symfony4 + rest api after installing rest api package check bundle files if fosrest bunfle is does not exits then add 
FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle::class => ['all' => true]

Comment: Please try to elaborate, how do you check and where do you add it? Provide a code example, please.

Comment: all used bundles are defined in config/bundles.php, in my case this was absent, I added it manually